# Target specific divs with nth-child

Tags: css

I've this code :

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I want to target the 2nd div, then the 5th div, the 8th div etc. to change their background.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class with an appropriate parameter:

```
div:nth-child(3n+2){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Please mark obvious duplicates as such rather than answering them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code,

```
div:nth-child(3n+2){
background:#00CC66;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div:nth-child(3n-1){
  background-color:red;
}
```

Check **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/0sjvg2ob/)**